# Minion Pro Package: '%' Sign Missing from the Roman (Regular) Typeface Only

Tags: fonts, packages, minionpro, texlive-2019

I’ve recently installed the Minion Pro package from https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro and followed all the instructions from the read-me file closely. So far, everything is rendering correctly *except for* the % sign for the regular typeface (see output example below), which is replaced by the crossed box sign.

I have tried other typefaces, and, oddly enough, for bold and italics, the % glyph renders just as it should.

To keep it clean, consider this simple output example for the following code (if that is unclear on the face of it, this package does not require `\usepackage[T1}{fontenc}` and even when using it, the results in pdf are exactly the same):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{MinionPro}

\begin{document}

Let us see if we can make it 100\%.
\textbf{More boldly, 100\%.}
\textit{Or, emphasised -- 100\%.}

$$\sum_{i=1}^NM^\alpha A^{1-\alpha}$$

\end{document}
```

This gives:
[image: The % sign is missing from the roman typeface only, but renders otherwise.]

I am using TexLive 2019 on Windows.

I have checked and confirmed that the .otf font files I used for conversion are not corrupt themselves – they give the correct glyphs in MS Word.

I specifically am not using font rendering using XeLaTeX or other such alternatives, as the MinionPro package is more powerful in detail and has its own maths support.

Is any fix already available out there? I have found none so far, someone else’s unanswered query on Stack Exchange from long ago touched exactly the same problem, but it got closed for not being    specific enough.

I am looking for proper fixes, not just workarounds.

Possibly, delving deeply into the files from the package, as installed in the TeX tree according to instructions, to see if a simple alteration of the code of one (or a few files) could fix it, may suffice to solve the problem, but I personally have no expertise nor time to find that on my own.

I will appreciate a sensible and informative response, as I really like that font.

(I have no in-depth knowledge of how packaging and font maps, and other such things work, so I would appreciate plain English explanations that would be ‘blindingly obvious’ also to simple users, and not just coding and command line savvies, please.)

**EDIT**
As requested, made a small file run through pdfLaTeX (called minion-2.tex) which contains just a % sign, and only MinionPro is used from packages. I obtained this formidable log:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (TeX Live 2019/W32TeX) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2019.12.18) 5 MAR 2020 18:34
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**minion-2.tex
(./minion-2.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro.sty
Package: MinionPro 2007/03/15 v2.1 MinionPro support for LaTeX
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro-FontDef.sty
File: MinionPro-FontDef.sty 2007/02/01 v2.2 font definition macros
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/otfontdef.sty
Package: otfontdef 2005/06/04 v0.1e OpenType font definition
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks14
))
\Mn@option@normalsize=\dimen103
Package MinionPro-FontDef Info: Configuration: smallfamily, noopticals, normals
ize=10.0pt on input line 52.
\Mn@config@cnt=\count88
\Mn@fontdimen=\dimen104
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
Package: textcomp 2018/08/11 v2.0j Standard LaTeX package
Package textcomp Info: Sub-encoding information:
(textcomp) 5 = only ISO-Adobe without \textcurrency
(textcomp) 4 = 5 + \texteuro
(textcomp) 3 = 4 + \textohm
(textcomp) 2 = 3 + \textestimated + \textcurrency
(textcomp) 1 = TS1 - \textcircled - \t
(textcomp) 0 = TS1 (full)
(textcomp) Font families with sub-encoding setting implement
(textcomp) only a restricted character set as indicated.
(textcomp) Family '?' is the default used for unknown fonts.
(textcomp) See the documentation for details.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ? sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line 79.
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def
File: ts1enc.def 2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
Now handling font encoding TS1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding TS1
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.dfu
File: ts1enc.dfu 2019/07/11 v1.2j UTF-8 support for inputenc
defining Unicode char U+00A2 (decimal 162)
defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
defining Unicode char U+00A4 (decimal 164)
defining Unicode char U+00A5 (decimal 165)
defining Unicode char U+00A6 (decimal 166)
defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
defining Unicode char U+00A8 (decimal 168)
defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
defining Unicode char U+00AC (decimal 172)
defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
defining Unicode char U+00AF (decimal 175)
defining Unicode char U+00B0 (decimal 176)
defining Unicode char U+00B1 (decimal 177)
defining Unicode char U+00B2 (decimal 178)
defining Unicode char U+00B3 (decimal 179)
defining Unicode char U+00B4 (decimal 180)
defining Unicode char U+00B5 (decimal 181)
defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
defining Unicode char U+00B9 (decimal 185)
defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
defining Unicode char U+00BC (decimal 188)
defining Unicode char U+00BD (decimal 189)
defining Unicode char U+00BE (decimal 190)
defining Unicode char U+00D7 (decimal 215)
defining Unicode char U+00F7 (decimal 247)
defining Unicode char U+0192 (decimal 402)
defining Unicode char U+02C7 (decimal 711)
defining Unicode char U+02D8 (decimal 728)
defining Unicode char U+02DD (decimal 733)
defining Unicode char U+0E3F (decimal 3647)
defining Unicode char U+2016 (decimal 8214)
defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
defining Unicode char U+2030 (decimal 8240)
defining Unicode char U+2031 (decimal 8241)
defining Unicode char U+203B (decimal 8251)
defining Unicode char U+203D (decimal 8253)
defining Unicode char U+2044 (decimal 8260)
defining Unicode char U+204E (decimal 8270)
defining Unicode char U+2052 (decimal 8274)
defining Unicode char U+20A1 (decimal 8353)
defining Unicode char U+20A4 (decimal 8356)
defining Unicode char U+20A6 (decimal 8358)
defining Unicode char U+20A9 (decimal 8361)
defining Unicode char U+20AB (decimal 8363)
defining Unicode char U+20AC (decimal 8364)
defining Unicode char U+20B1 (decimal 8369)
defining Unicode char U+2103 (decimal 8451)
defining Unicode char U+2116 (decimal 8470)
defining Unicode char U+2117 (decimal 8471)
defining Unicode char U+211E (decimal 8478)
defining Unicode char U+2120 (decimal 8480)
defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
defining Unicode char U+2126 (decimal 8486)
defining Unicode char U+2127 (decimal 8487)
defining Unicode char U+212E (decimal 8494)
defining Unicode char U+2190 (decimal 8592)
defining Unicode char U+2191 (decimal 8593)
defining Unicode char U+2192 (decimal 8594)
defining Unicode char U+2193 (decimal 8595)
defining Unicode char U+2329 (decimal 9001)
defining Unicode char U+232A (decimal 9002)
defining Unicode char U+2422 (decimal 9250)
defining Unicode char U+25E6 (decimal 9702)
defining Unicode char U+25EF (decimal 9711)
defining Unicode char U+266A (decimal 9834)
defining Unicode char U+27E8 (decimal 10216)
defining Unicode char U+27E9 (decimal 10217)
defining Unicode char U+FEFF (decimal 65279)
))
LaTeX Info: Redefining \oldstylenums on input line 334.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 349.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 350.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 351.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 352.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmbr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 353.
Package textcomp Info: Setting cmtl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 354.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ccr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 355.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptm sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 356.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pcr sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 357.
Package textcomp Info: Setting phv sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 358.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ppl sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 359.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pag sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 360.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pbk sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 361.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pnc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 362.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pzc sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 363.
Package textcomp Info: Setting bch sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 364.
Package textcomp Info: Setting put sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 365.
Package textcomp Info: Setting uag sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 366.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ugq sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 367.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul8 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 368.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ul9 sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 369.
Package textcomp Info: Setting augie sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 370.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayrom sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 371.
Package textcomp Info: Setting dayroms sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 372.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 373.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 374.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pxtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 375.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 376.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 377.
Package textcomp Info: Setting txtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 378.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 379.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmdh sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 380.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmss sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 381.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmssq sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 382.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmvtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 383.
Package textcomp Info: Setting lmtt sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 384.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhv sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 385.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qag sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 386.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qbk sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 387.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcr sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 388.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qcs sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 389.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qpl sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 390.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qtm sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 391.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qzc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 392.
Package textcomp Info: Setting qhvc sub-encoding to TS1/0 on input line 393.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futs sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 394.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 395.
Package textcomp Info: Setting futj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 396.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlh sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 397.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hls sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 398.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlst sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 399.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlct sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 400.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlx sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 401.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlce sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 402.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcn sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 403.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcw sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 404.
Package textcomp Info: Setting hlcf sub-encoding to TS1/5 on input line 405.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplx sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 406.
Package textcomp Info: Setting pplj sub-encoding to TS1/3 on input line 407.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmx sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 408.
Package textcomp Info: Setting ptmj sub-encoding to TS1/4 on input line 409.
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/mnsymbol/MnSymbol.sty
Package: MnSymbol 2007/01/21 v1.4 support for the MnSymbol font
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsmath.sty
Package: amsmath 2019/11/16 v2.17d AMS math features
\@mathmargin=\skip43
For additional information on amsmath, use the `?' option.
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amstext.sty
Package: amstext 2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsgen.sty
File: amsgen.sty 1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
\@emptytoks=\toks15
\ex@=\dimen105
))
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsbsy.sty
Package: amsbsy 1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
\pmbraise@=\dimen106
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsmath/amsopn.sty
Package: amsopn 2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
)
\inf@bad=\count89
LaTeX Info: Redefining \frac on input line 227.
\uproot@=\count90
\leftroot@=\count91
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overline on input line 389.
\classnum@=\count92
\DOTSCASE@=\count93
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ldots on input line 486.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dots on input line 489.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cdots on input line 610.
\Mathstrutbox@=\box27
\strutbox@=\box28
\big@size=\dimen107
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OML on input line 733.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring font encoding OMS on input line 734.
\macc@depth=\count94
\c@MaxMatrixCols=\count95
\dotsspace@=\muskip10
\c@parentequation=\count96
\dspbrk@lvl=\count97
\tag@help=\toks16
\row@=\count98
\column@=\count99
\maxfields@=\count100
\andhelp@=\toks17
\eqnshift@=\dimen108
\alignsep@=\dimen109
\tagshift@=\dimen110
\tagwidth@=\dimen111
\totwidth@=\dimen112
\lineht@=\dimen113
\@envbody=\toks18
\multlinegap=\skip44
\multlinetaggap=\skip45
\mathdisplay@stack=\toks19
LaTeX Info: Redefining \[ on input line 2858.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \] on input line 2859.
)
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/amsfonts/eufrak.sty
Package: eufrak 2009/06/22 v3.00 Euler Fraktur fonts
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\EuFrak' in version `bold'
(Font) U/euf/m/n --> U/euf/b/n on input line 39.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \dagger on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ddagger on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathparagraph on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathsection on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathdollar on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \mathsterling on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Re on input line 84.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Im on input line 84.
\symMnSyA=\mathgroup4
\symMnSyB=\mathgroup5
\symMnSyC=\mathgroup6
\symMnSyD=\mathgroup7
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `largesymbols' on input line 119.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n on input line 119.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMX/cmex/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n on input line 119.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `symbols' on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OMS' has changed to `U' for symbol font
(Font) `symbols' in the math version `normal' on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `normal'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/m/n --> U/MnSymbolF/m/n on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OMS' has changed to `U' for symbol font
(Font) `symbols' in the math version `bold' on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/cmsy/b/n --> U/MnSymbolF/m/n on input line 120.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `MnSyA' in version `bold'
(Font) U/MnSymbolA/m/n --> U/MnSymbolA/b/n on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `MnSyB' in version `bold'
(Font) U/MnSymbolB/m/n --> U/MnSymbolB/b/n on input line 122.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `MnSyC' in version `bold'
(Font) U/MnSymbolC/m/n --> U/MnSymbolC/b/n on input line 123.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `MnSyD' in version `bold'
(Font) U/MnSymbolD/m/n --> U/MnSymbolD/b/n on input line 124.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `largesymbols' in version `bold'
(Font) OMX/MnSymbolE/m/n --> OMX/MnSymbolE/b/n on input line 1
25.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `symbols' in version `bold'
(Font) U/MnSymbolF/m/n --> U/MnSymbolF/b/n on input line 126.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathcal on input line 241.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathcal' in version `bold'
(Font) OMS/MnSymbolS/m/n --> OMS/MnSymbolS/b/n on input line 2
41.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longrightarrow on input line 548.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftarrow on input line 549.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longleftrightarrow on input line 550.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longrightarrow on input line 551.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftarrow on input line 552.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \Longleftrightarrow on input line 553.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \longmapsto on input line 554.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \vdots on input line 868.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lfloor on input line 1660.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rfloor on input line 1661.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lceil on input line 1662.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rceil on input line 1663.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \vert on input line 1673.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lvert on input line 1676.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rvert on input line 1677.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \Vert on input line 1678.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lVert on input line 1681.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rVert on input line 1682.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \arrowvert on input line 1683.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \Arrowvert on input line 1684.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \langle on input line 1692.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rangle on input line 1693.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \backslash on input line 1699.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lbrace on input line 1704.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rbrace on input line 1705.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lgroup on input line 1706.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rgroup on input line 1707.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \rmoustache on input line 1708.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \lmoustache on input line 1709.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math delimiter \bracevert on input line 1710.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \braceld on input line 1721.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \bracelu on input line 1722.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \bracerd on input line 1723.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \braceru on input line 1724.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \downbracefill on input line 1799.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upbracefill on input line 1800.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \overbrace on input line 1819.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \underbrace on input line 1820.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \surd on input line 1843.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \widehat on input line 1845.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \widetilde on input line 1846.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \vec on input line 1848.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `operators' on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font) `operators' in the math version `normal' on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info: Encoding `OT1' has changed to `T1' for symbol font
(Font) `operators' in the math version `bold' on input line 163.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n on input line 163
.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring symbol font `letters' on input line 164.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `normal'
(Font) OML/cmm/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line
164.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/cmm/b/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line
164.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `bold'
(Font) T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input
line 165.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `bold'
(Font) OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on
input line 166.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathbf on input line 167.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input line 16
7.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathbf' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/n --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/n on input line 16
7.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math alphabet \mathit on input line 168.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `normal'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it on input line 16
8.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) OT1/cmr/bx/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it on input line 1
68.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `bold'
(Font) T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-OsF/eb/it on inp
ut line 169.
\c@mv@tabular=\count101
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `tabular'
(Font) T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/m/n on input
line 171.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `tabular'
(Font) OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on
input line 172.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `tabular'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it on input line 1
73.
\c@mv@boldtabular=\count102
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `operators' in version `boldtabular
'
(Font) T1/MinionPro-OsF/m/n --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/n on inpu
t line 176.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting symbol font `letters' in version `boldtabular'
(Font) OML/MinionPro-TOsF/m/it --> OML/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on
input line 177.
LaTeX Font Info: Overwriting math alphabet `\mathit' in version `boldtabular
'
(Font) OT1/cmr/m/it --> T1/MinionPro-TOsF/eb/it on input line
178.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \grave on input line 179.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \acute on input line 180.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \hat on input line 181.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \tilde on input line 182.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \ddot on input line 183.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \mathring on input line 184.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \check on input line 185.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \breve on input line 186.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \bar on input line 187.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math accent \dot on input line 188.
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2007/03/31 v0.2b Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 26.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 28.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 34.
)
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \hbar on input line 497.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \partial on input line 499.
LaTeX Font Info: Redeclaring math symbol \ell on input line 501.
Package textcomp Info: Setting MinionPro-LF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input line
521.
Package textcomp Info: Setting MinionPro-TLF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input lin
e 522.
Package textcomp Info: Setting MinionPro-OsF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input lin
e 523.
Package textcomp Info: Setting MinionPro-TOsF sub-encoding to TS1/1 on input li
ne 524.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \LaTeX on input line 596.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for OT1+MinionPro-OsF on in
put line 628.
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/OT1MinionPro-OsF.fd
File: OT1MinionPro-OsF.fd 2005/01/23 v2.0 font definitions for OT1/MinionPro-Os
F.
(c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/MinionPro/MinionPro-FontDef.sty
File: MinionPro-FontDef.sty 2007/02/01 v2.2 font definition macros
)))
(./minion-2.aux)
\openout1 = `minion-2.aux'.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info: Trying to load font information for TS1+cmr on input line 4
.
(c:/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd
File: ts1cmr.fd 2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info: ... okay on input line 4.
[1
{c:/texlive/2019/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./minion-2.aux
) )
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5015 strings out of 492163
68053 string characters out of 6129075
88178 words of memory out of 5000000
9404 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
8962 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
45i,4n,63p,266b,398s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-aa.enc}<c:/
texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/MinionPro-Regular.pfb
pdfTeX warning: pdflatex.exe (file c:/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/type1/adobe/Min
ionPro/MinionPro-Regular.pfb): glyph `percent.oldstyle' undefined
>
Output written on minion-2.pdf (1 page, 7805 bytes).
PDF statistics:
13 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
8 compressed objects within 1 object stream
0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: That word shows a glyph doesn't mean that it is in the font. What do you get if you try with lualatex and fontspec? And regarding the "blindingly obvious": You chose the complicated way yourself. If you want to use a open type font without much fuss, use xelatex or lualatex.

Comment: According to FontForge, on my system (Ubuntu, font taken from Adobe Reader 9) MinionPro-Regular.otf contains the percent sign, at the same position and with the same general properties as MinionPro-Bold.otf. Can you verify that this is also the case on your system (with FontForge or a similar font inspection program, Microsoft Word is not reliable as a test because it will replace missing characters automatically)?

Comment: **Workaround.** Ok, when running LuaLaTex with fontspec, the percentage sign is finally there. However, it requires to include the MinionPro package (before `\setmainfont`, otherwise the text is in cm and the maths in Minion Pro) anyway if I want to have mathematical equations using the same font and not cm, and throws up a warning about a line 628 in MinionPro.sty (because the package wants itself to impose the main font, understandably). So, although I don't like workarounds, this is a satisfactory one. I hope that someone could find a more elegant and general solution though.

Comment: I've checked with FontForge, the % glyph is there in MinionPro-Regular.otf; also, the workaround I used above still fails to throw up % in the equation environment, so it looks like the problem with the package itself

Comment: Write a small document which uses only the faulty % and show the log-file.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I have added the log to the main question (it's lengthy)

Comment: At the end you find `glyph `percent.oldstyle' undefined` .  You could open the .pfb (or the afm if you have it) in some editor. Perhaps you can see if the glyph has another name. Or you could open the base-MinionPro-aa.enc and replace `percent.oldstyle` by `percent`.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! The glyph is called simply 'percent' in the pfb file, and the substitution has removed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

The solution (credits to Ulrike Fischer, see comments under the question) is as follows for anyone interested:

Go to  `/texmf-local/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro` (assuming the whole package installed correctly) and open `base-MinionPro-aa.enc` with, for instance, Notepad. There, search for ‘percent’ (under `0xD0`) and you will see—

```
% 0xD0
 /emdash /oacute /ocircumflex /ograve /one.fitted /one.oldstyle /one.superior /one.taboldstyle
 /onehalf /onequarter /otilde /percent.oldstyle /plusminus /registered /seven.fitted /seven.oldstyle
```

Change `percent.oldstyle` to `percent`, that is

```
% 0xD0
 /emdash /oacute /ocircumflex /ograve /one.fitted /one.oldstyle /one.superior /one.taboldstyle
 /onehalf /onequarter /otilde /percent /plusminus /registered /seven.fitted /seven.oldstyle
```

and save the file.
As the glyph’s name in the .pfb file (in folder `type1`) is ‘percent’, the encoding file must have corresponding information in order to work.

Voilà, Minion Pro can now be enjoyed in pdfLaTeX without workarounds that produce warnings. Compare the output for the same code as in the question:

[image: fixed issue with the percent glyph for Minion Pro]